# Git status to see files with whitespace only changes?

Tags: git

It appears my Git options includes `--ignore-space-change` as `git status` won't list files with only whitespace changes.  How can I see the diffs and commit files with only whitespace changes?

Comment: You want to see change files that only include white spaces in the diff?

Comment: While `git status` runs `git diff` (twice), it sets very specific flags for each of its two `git diff` commands and you cannot change these flags. If you want your own (different) specific `git diff` flags, you must run the `git diff` command(s) yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This will show uncommitted files that only contain whitespace changes. It could be adapted to examine a commit by adding extra args to `git diff`

```
FILES=`git diff --name-only`
for x in `git diff -G [a-zA-Z0-9]; do
  FILES=`echo "FILES" | grep -v $x`
done
echo $FILES
```

`git diff --name-only` Gets a list of all files with changes.
`git diff -g [a-zA-Z0-9]` Gets all files with changes that contain a letter or num
Loop though each file
`grep -v $x` Removes any files from the list that contains a letter or num

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the list of files with only whitespace changes to give a targeted commit message apart from other pending changes.

This solution works for me, it doesn't attempt to handle odd whitespace in filenames, nor renamed/copied/added/removed files, nor file mode changes:

```
git diff --numstat --ignore-all-space |
    perl -lane '$add=shift @F; $del=shift @F; print "@F" unless ($add + $del)'
```